# Where to see Sentry messages in the dashboard?

Tags: javascript, react-native, sentry

I am using `react-native` library for sentry, doing `Sentry.captureMessage(message, Sentry.Severity.Warning)`. I can't find any place in the dashboard, where this message would show. If I call `Sentry.captureException` it does show in issues, but I don't want to flood it with warnings. Where in the dashboard can I see whether the message is received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get it in the `issues` section, as long with the other issues.

I executed that code : `Sentry.captureMessage('this is an error message', Sentry.Severity.Warning);`

**1. My issues list :**

[image]

**2. Inside the 'message' issue**:

[image]

**Important:** check in your browser network console, if the `api/<id>/store/?sentry_key...` call exists.